# Cakephp Logout and rederect not working in hostgator

Tags: php, cakephp

Yesterday everything is fine but today the logout function does not work anymore and access to the path / users no longer valid but when I run / users / index its worck here is an explanatory video and my code https://youtu.be/C-1aUF2I-ac

class UsersController extends AppController {

```
function beforeFilter()
{
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow('login','add');

        $this->Auth->authError = __('Vous devez être connecté.');
        $this->Auth->loginError = __('E-mail ou mot de passe invalide, veuillez réessayer');
}
    function login()
    {
        if ($this->request->is('post'))
        {
            if ($this->Auth->login())
            {
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'view'));
            }
        }
    }
public function logout()
    {
        $this->Auth->logout();
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'login'));
    }

    public function index() 
    {
            $this->paginate = array(
            'limit' => 1000,
            'order' => array(
                'User.id' => 'desc'
            ));
            $this->User->recursive = 0;
            $this->set('users', $this->paginate());
   }
```

AppController.php

```
class AppController extends Controller
{
    var $components = array('Auth','Session');
    function beforeFilter()
    {
         //$this->Auth->allow(array('*'));
    }
}
```

in my hebergeur i have php 5.6.29
version for cake is 2.3.4

Comment: how is your logout redirect in appController ? post that code too.

Comment: i add appcontroller and userscontroller   But the website have worck perfectly in my local and its worck perfectly yastorday in server and now is broken i d'ont touch anyting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup I am having same problem with hostgator server. I am trying to figure out the problem. Currently session not being destroyed and cache not being cleared. Normally cakephp does not put login and logout in cache.

Comment: yes you have reson  if you got the solution please help me

Comment: Cookie is being set locally with localhost thats the reason live server logout is not working. I tried with different computer where I am not developing the application and the logout works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

paste the full code with controller and app controller
and be sure that you have not allow the function in your before filter

Comment: i add appcontroller and userscontroller   But the website have worck perfectly in my local and its worck perfectly yastorday in server and now is broken i d'ont touch anyting